# Pandas: Convert datetime series to an int by month

Tags: date, datetime, pandas, integer, time-series

I have a dataframe that contains a series of dates, e.g.:

```
0    2014-06-17
1    2014-05-05
2    2014-01-07
3    2014-06-29
4    2014-03-15
5    2014-06-06
7    2014-01-29
```

What I would like to do is convert these dates to `integers` by the `month`, since all the values are within the same year. So I would like to get something like this:

```
0    6
1    5
2    1
3    6
4    3
5    6
7    1
```

Is there a quick way to do this with Pandas?

EDIT: Answered by jezrael. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use function [`dt.month`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.month.html):

```
print (df)
       Dates
0 2014-06-17
1 2014-05-05
2 2014-01-07
3 2014-06-29
4 2014-03-15
5 2014-06-06
6 2014-01-29


print (df.Dates.dt.month)
0    6
1    5
2    1
3    6
4    3
5    6
6    1
Name: Dates, dtype: int64
```